# Calories counting loop

Tags: c++, while-loop

Question:
Create a program that first asks the user to enter the number of items he/she has eaten today and then to enter the number of calories for each item. It then calculates the number of calories he/she has eaten for the day and displays the value.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int numberOfItems;
    int count; // loop counter for the loop
    int caloriesForItem;
    int totalCalories;
    cout << "How many items did you eat today? ";
    cin >> numberOfItems;
    cout << "Enter the number of calories in each of the " << numberOfItems << " items eaten:" >> endl;

    while (caloriesForItem)
    {
        cout << "Please enter item calories:";
        cin >>caloriesForItem;
        count == numberOfItems;

    }


    cout << "Total calories eaten today = " << totalCalories;
    return 0;
}
```

In the end I'm not sure how I would make it read and calculate as it says it must be a while loop.

Answer (score 0):

You have all of your pieces already.  You have a `count` for your loop, a `totalCalories` tracker, and a variable to hold the current items `caloriesForItem`.  Every iteration of your loop must increase the `count`, and every iteration must retrieve a new value for `caloriesForItem`.  You can add this each time to `totalCalories`.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int numberOfItems;
    int caloriesForItem;
    // These two variables need to have a start value
    int count = 0;
    int totalCalories = 0;

    cout << "How many items did you eat today? ";
    cin >> numberOfItems;
    cout << "Enter the number of calories in each of the " << numberOfItems << " items eaten:" >> endl;

    // Loop for as many times as you have items to enter
    while (count < numberOfItems)
    {
        cout << "Please enter item calories:";
        // Read in next value
        cin >> caloriesForItem;
        // Add new value to total
        totalCalories += caloriesForItem;
        // Increase count so you know how many items you have processed.
        count++;
    }

    cout << "Total calories eaten today = " << totalCalories;
    return 0;
}
```

You were pretty close though.
(I added comments in the appropriate places to explain whats going on.)

Lastly I want to add that you pretty much can convert any `for` loop to a `while` loop using this themplate:

```
for( <init_var>; <condition>; <step> ) {
  // code
}
```

becomes

```
<init_var>;

while( <condition> ) {
  // code

  <step>;
}
```

**Example:**

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10 i++) {
  cout << i << endl;
}
```

becomes

```
int i = 0;

while(i < 10) {
  cout << i << endl;

  i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int numberOfItems, caloriesForItem, totalCalories=0;
    cout << "How many items did you eat today? ";
    cin >> numberOfItems;
    cout << "Enter the number of calories in each of the " << numberOfItems << " items eaten:" << endl;

    while (numberOfItems--)
    {
        cout << "Please enter item calories:";
        cin >> caloriesForItem;
        totalCalories += caloriesForItem;
    }

    cout << "Total calories eaten today = " << totalCalories;
    return 0;
}
```

It's a sufficient way to do what you wanted, if you don't understand, let me know!